# Cannot link to SDL2 libs while compiling

Tags: linux, build, compilation, sdl, lib

I'm attempting to compile an application that requires SDL2. I have all the dependencies already installed on my system (an Arch-based Linux distribution).
But for some reason, the linker fails to find the required SDL2 libraries.

I try:

make *parameters*

*builds several things successfully, then:*

```
Linking...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunwind-generic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunwind
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libus-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldbus-1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:169: build/release] Error 1
```

Accordingly to

```
ldconfig -p | grep SDL
```

My system has:

```
    libSDL2pp.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2pp.so.8
    libSDL2pp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2pp.so
    libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2-2.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so
    libSDL2-2.0.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL2-2.0.so
    libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0
    libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0
    libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1
    libSDL_net-1.2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL_net-1.2.so.0
    libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
    libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
    libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
    libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libSDL-1.2.so.0
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you compile/link minimal program using SDL2 (like only SDL_Init)? If not, please edit in test program, build command, and its full output.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing some [files](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/sdl2/files/) from the list in the arch linux package. Most importantly, libSDL2.so.  Might want to retry your install and use a package manager if possible.

Comment: I have the package sdl2 installed, and it appears I do have the file. `ls /usr/lib/ | grep libSDL2.so` returns me `libSDL2.so`.